# translate(localize) specific title of web form use preprocess func

Tags: 7

I have specific webform call careers , i have use webform localization model but the model does not translate the node title , some one told me to use  preprocess node func. but i did not now how to create theme i try to write some thing like this

```
function [themeName]_preprocess_page(&$variables) {  
  if($node['id'] == 6) {
  $node['title'] = t($node['title']); 
    }
```

But it does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code doesn't work because the function receives only a parameter, and that is not `$node`. The correct code should eventually be the following one.

```
function mymodule_preprocess_page(&$variables) {  
  if(!empty($variables['node']) && $variables['node']->nid == 6) {
    $variables['title'] = t($variables['title']); 
  }
}
```

I am assuming you want to change the title when the node ID is equal to 6.